# Multiplication of two factors with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following to multiply ;

$$(z-p-qi+\sqrt{t+ui})(z-p+qi+\sqrt{t-ui})$$

Now, I think that the product must not have any complex numbers...

But here is what I get

$$z^2-2zp+p^2+q^1+\sqrt{t^2+u^2}+(\sqrt{t-ui}+\sqrt{t+ui})(z-p+qi)$$

I'm pretty sure that there is some step that I'm missing... Can anybody point me out my error ?
Thanks

Comment: why are you assuming that the answer will not have any complex numbers? In fact the two numbers you are multiplying need not be complex conjugates (because of the presence of $z$).

Comment: For no particular reason, I just thought that they needed to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a mistake about sign. See the red sign at the last.
$$(z-p-qi+\sqrt{t+ui})(z-p+qi+\sqrt{t-ui})$$
$$=z^2+z(-p+qi)+z\sqrt{t-ui}+z(-p-qi)+(-p-qi)(-p+qi)+(-p-qi)\sqrt{t-ui}+z\sqrt{t+ui}+(-p+qi)\sqrt{t+ui}+\sqrt{(t+ui)(t-ui)}$$
$$=z^2+z(-p+qi-p-qi)+z(\sqrt{t-ui}+\sqrt{t+ui})+p^2+q^2+(-p-qi)\sqrt{t-ui}+(-p+qi)\sqrt{t+ui}+\sqrt{t^2+u^2}$$
$$=z^2-2pz+z(\sqrt{t-ui}+\sqrt{t+ui})+p^2+q^2+(-p-qi)\sqrt{t-ui}+(-p+qi)\sqrt{t+ui}+\sqrt{t^2+u^2}$$
$$=z^2-2pz+p^2+q^2+\sqrt{t^2+u^2}+(z-p)(\sqrt{t-ui}+\sqrt{t+ui})+qi(\sqrt{t+ui}\color{red}{-}\sqrt{t-ui})$$

Comment: Mmmmh...My two factors are written in the correct way... But, as I see, we can't get rid of the complex parts, can't we ??

Comment: @Astroman: I think we cannot. Why do you think that it must not have any complex numbers? Because of some answers in a book?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I guess it's some error

Comment: @Astroman: Can you write the answer?

Comment: Here : http://imgur.com/LTbx3hS The idea is that we want to express it in a quadratic form..

Comment: @Astroman: Ah, I see. This is because $\sqrt{t-ui}+\sqrt{t+ui}=\sqrt{2t+2\sqrt{t^2+u^2}}$ and $i\sqrt{t+ui}-i\sqrt{t-ui}=\sqrt{-2t+2\sqrt{t^2+u^2}}$. To see this, you can square both sides.

Comment: Ok, I see that they are equal when I square them, but I don't see how you established this relationship between the two.... How do you get this equality ?

Comment: @Astroman: Well, I just compared it with my answer :)

Comment: Yes, but how was I supposed to see this equality ? I mean, this isn't obvious and doesn't seem natural if you ask me.. I would have spent 1 hour and chances I would still have a hard time finding this relationship

Comment: @Astroman: I might agree with you, but squaring something must be helpful especially in the case when you have $\sqrt{a+bi}+\sqrt{a-bi}$ or something like this. (you should know why)

Comment: Ok, yes. At the same time, my mathematical suitcase isn't that big. (I learned only to differential/integral calculus) Thank you again for you help !

Comment: @Astroman: You are welcome! Very glad if it helps. Enjoy learning math!

Comment: The (principal) square root of 2 complex conjugates are complex conjugates themselves, so their sum is real, and their difference is imaginary